# Why does jquery resizable alsoresize look smooth but providing a function on event resize isnt?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So I'm using jQuery resizable and I find that using the 'alsoResize' of resizable has some unwanted effects on my elements. So instead I figured that I would just bind to the 'resize' event and perform my own custom actions. What I don't understand is why when using alsoresize the effect is smooth...specifically noting when scrollbars come in. Yet performing a small action on 'resize'

```
that.box.height(that.host.Content.outerHeight() - that.header.outerHeight());
```

cause the effect to be choppy or slow. I suppose its not like its slow.. its more like its not re-rendering the elements in time... but once I stop resizing, the function takes full effect and is in the proper place.

Any insight would be much appreciated on why this would happen.

Comment: I found the issue. On one of the higher level div's i was using width and height as 'inherit' and that was slowing it down... changing those to 100% seems to have fixed the issue, though i cant imagine why 'inherit' is that much of a burden to the render as opposed to 100%;

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it has to do with how fast the resize event is firing. When you resize something the event fires continuously (hundreds of times perhaps). If the redraw effect is intensive then this will cause performance problems. In order to combat this you should use a setTimeout and only perform your redraws every x number of milliseconds. You should be able to find a happy medium between smoothness and performance as long as the operation isn't too intensive.

Update - I decided to add some pseudocode

```
var go = true;
var timeout;

$(element).resize( function() {
  if (go) { 
    //your code

    //
    go = false;
    timeout = setTimeout('go = true', 100);        
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is **throttle** the code that you are calling in your resize function. this is a good throttlejquery plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

also underscore.js has a good throttle impl